# Bitnami Django Stack admin site does not work

Tags: python, django, apache, bitnami

I have Bitnami Django stack version 1.8.7-2 installed. I have created a TryDjango Project. The default project is Project.

But when I access

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/TryDjango/admin/
```

It shows me the view break:

[image: Error django admin]

And when I'm logged in. It throws me these errors:
[image: Logged in erros]

These are my settings:

```
Using settings module Project.settings
Setting Value
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER   
False
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
LANGUAGE_CODE   
'en-us'
ROOT_URLCONF    
'Project.urls'
LOGIN_URL   
'/accounts/login/'
BASE_DIR    
'C:\\Users\\Juan\\Bitnami Django Stack projects\\Project'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS  
[]
DEFAULT_CHARSET 
'utf-8'
SESSION_SERIALIZER  
'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
STATIC_ROOT 
None
ALLOWED_HOSTS   
[]
MESSAGE_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX    
'[Django] '
SERVER_EMAIL    
'root@localhost'
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS 
0
STATICFILES_FINDERS 
('django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder')
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS 
'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   
None
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME 
'sessionid'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
('%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M')
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT  
[]
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
             'HOST': '',
             'NAME': 'djangostack',
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': u'********************',
             'PORT': '54322',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC',
             'USER': 'bitnami'}}
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE   
u'********************'
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS   
None
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS 
None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    
('django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler')
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE    
'text/html'
APPEND_SLASH    
True
LOCALE_PATHS    
()
DATABASE_ROUTERS    
[]
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  
''
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT   
'F Y'
STATICFILES_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
CACHES  
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH 
'/'
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF 
False
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES  
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')
USE_I18N    
True
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
','
SECRET_KEY  
u'********************'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    
'django_language'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE    
''
LOGGING_CONFIG  
'logging.config.dictConfig'
TEMPLATE_LOADERS    
('django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader')
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK   
0
WSGI_APPLICATION    
'Project.wsgi.application'
TEMPLATE_DEBUG  
False
X_FRAME_OPTIONS 
'SAMEORIGIN'
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    
'csrftoken'
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME   
None
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST    
False
EMAIL_TIMEOUT   
None
SECURE_SSL_HOST 
None
SIGNING_BACKEND 
'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   
False
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
FILE_CHARSET    
'utf-8'
DEBUG   
True
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    
'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
INSTALLED_APPS  
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
LANGUAGES   
(('af', 'Afrikaans'),
 ('ar', 'Arabic'),
 ('ast', 'Asturian'),
 ('az', 'Azerbaijani'),
 ('bg', 'Bulgarian'),
 ('be', 'Belarusian'),
 ('bn', 'Bengali'),
 ('br', 'Breton'),
 ('bs', 'Bosnian'),
 ('ca', 'Catalan'),
 ('cs', 'Czech'),
 ('cy', 'Welsh'),
 ('da', 'Danish'),
 ('de', 'German'),
 ('el', 'Greek'),
 ('en', 'English'),
 ('en-au', 'Australian English'),
 ('en-gb', 'British English'),
 ('eo', 'Esperanto'),
 ('es', 'Spanish'),
 ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'),
 ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'),
 ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'),
 ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'),
 ('et', 'Estonian'),
 ('eu', 'Basque'),
 ('fa', 'Persian'),
 ('fi', 'Finnish'),
 ('fr', 'French'),
 ('fy', 'Frisian'),
 ('ga', 'Irish'),
 ('gl', 'Galician'),
 ('he', 'Hebrew'),
 ('hi', 'Hindi'),
 ('hr', 'Croatian'),
 ('hu', 'Hungarian'),
 ('ia', 'Interlingua'),
 ('id', 'Indonesian'),
 ('io', 'Ido'),
 ('is', 'Icelandic'),
 ('it', 'Italian'),
 ('ja', 'Japanese'),
 ('ka', 'Georgian'),
 ('kk', 'Kazakh'),
 ('km', 'Khmer'),
 ('kn', 'Kannada'),
 ('ko', 'Korean'),
 ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'),
 ('lt', 'Lithuanian'),
 ('lv', 'Latvian'),
 ('mk', 'Macedonian'),
 ('ml', 'Malayalam'),
 ('mn', 'Mongolian'),
 ('mr', 'Marathi'),
 ('my', 'Burmese'),
 ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmal'),
 ('ne', 'Nepali'),
 ('nl', 'Dutch'),
 ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'),
 ('os', 'Ossetic'),
 ('pa', 'Punjabi'),
 ('pl', 'Polish'),
 ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
 ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'),
 ('ro', 'Romanian'),
 ('ru', 'Russian'),
 ('sk', 'Slovak'),
 ('sl', 'Slovenian'),
 ('sq', 'Albanian'),
 ('sr', 'Serbian'),
 ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'),
 ('sv', 'Swedish'),
 ('sw', 'Swahili'),
 ('ta', 'Tamil'),
 ('te', 'Telugu'),
 ('th', 'Thai'),
 ('tr', 'Turkish'),
 ('tt', 'Tatar'),
 ('udm', 'Udmurt'),
 ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
 ('ur', 'Urdu'),
 ('vi', 'Vietnamese'),
 ('zh-cn', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese'),
 ('zh-tw', 'Traditional Chinese'))
USE_L10N    
True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  
False
STATICFILES_DIRS    
()
PREPEND_WWW 
False
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER 
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE 
None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY 
True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS  
False
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE 
31449600
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT    
'F j'
MANAGERS    
()
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE 
False
TIME_FORMAT 
'P'
AUTH_USER_MODEL 
'auth.User'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS  
('%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y',
 '%b %d %Y',
 '%b %d, %Y',
 '%d %b %Y',
 '%d %b, %Y',
 '%B %d %Y',
 '%B %d, %Y',
 '%d %B %Y',
 '%d %B, %Y')
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS 
('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD 
u'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS 
u'********************'
SESSION_FILE_PATH   
None
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  
'default'
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST  
False
NUMBER_GROUPING 
0
SESSION_ENGINE  
'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   
'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  
'/accounts/profile/'
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR   
'.'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS  
()
MIGRATION_MODULES   
{}
TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID  
''
LOGOUT_URL  
'/accounts/logout/'
EMAIL_USE_TLS   
False
FIXTURE_DIRS    
()
EMAIL_HOST  
'localhost'
DATE_FORMAT 
'N j, Y'
MEDIA_ROOT  
''
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER   
'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
ADMINS  
()
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH  
None
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  
'webmaster@localhost'
MEDIA_URL   
''
DATETIME_FORMAT 
'N j, Y, P'
TEMPLATE_DIRS   
()
EXAMPLE_DATABASES   
{'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
             'NAME': 'C:\\Users\\Juan\\Bitnami Django Stack projects\\Project\\db.sqlite3'}}
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS  
()
ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS   
()
LOGGING 
{}
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y'
TEMPLATES   
[{'APP_DIRS': True,
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': [],
  'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]
TEST_RUNNER 
'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX 
u'********************'
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT 
False
TIME_ZONE   
'UTC'
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
EMAIL_BACKEND   
'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_SSL   
False
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS 
('django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
 'django.template.context_processors.debug',
 'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
 'django.template.context_processors.media',
 'django.template.context_processors.static',
 'django.template.context_processors.tz',
 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages')
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE  
1209600
SETTINGS_MODULE 
'Project.settings'
USE_ETAGS   
False
LANGUAGES_BIDI  
('he', 'ar', 'fa', 'ur')
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    
None
INTERNAL_IPS    
()
STATIC_URL  
'/Project/static/'
EMAIL_PORT  
25
USE_TZ  
True
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y P'
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS    
[]
PASSWORD_HASHERS    
u'********************'
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES  
{}
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    
600
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE  
None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
 '%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%y')
EMAIL_HOST_USER 
''
```

Can you help me please.

I have run python manage.py collectstatic and throws me these error:

```
C:\Users\Juan\Bitnami Django Stack projects\TryDjango>python manage.py collectst
atic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Bitnami\djangostack-1.8.7-2\apps\django\django-1.8.7-py2.7.egg\django
\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Bitnami\djangostack-1.8.7-2\apps\django\django-1.8.7-py2.7.egg\django
\core\management\__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Bitnami\djangostack-1.8.7-2\apps\django\django-1.8.7-py2.7.egg\django
\core\management\__init__.py", line 190, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Bitnami\djangostack-1.8.7-2\apps\django\django-1.8.7-py2.7.egg\django
\core\management\__init__.py", line 41, in load_command_class
    return module.Command()
  File "C:\Bitnami\djangostack-1.8.7-2\apps\django\django-1.8.7-py2.7.egg\django
\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 32, in __init__

    self.storage.path('')
  File "C:\Bitnami\djangostack-1.8.7-2\apps\django\django-1.8.7-py2.7.egg\django
\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 48, in path
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app wi
thout having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.

C:\Users\Juan\Bitnami Django Stack projects\TryDjango>
```

Comment: try `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: @qasimalbaqali  I have updated my question with the result of the python manage. py collectstatic command

Comment: The error message is telling you to set `STATIC_ROOT` in settings.

Comment: @thebjorn how I set the STATIC_ROOT??

Comment: I'm sure google can tell you how to set STATIC_ROOT, although it is irrelevant if you're running in development (settings.DEBUG should be True) - then Django should serve static files from your app's static folder. You really need to read and understand https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/  The error you're getting about `auth_user` not existing is because you haven't run `manage.py syncdb` (or `manage.py migrate` if you're on a recent Django).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry i am late to the party, anyway the error is from your database.
It seems you have not created the core user table yet.

you need to run the following command as soon as you create your django project and setup your database:

> python manage.py migrate

This will create the django core tables
it is only after this, that you can create a superuser

now run the following code to create a super user account  and follow  the prompts to create a username and password.

> python manage.py createsuperuser

Note that, if you dont migrate the core tables first you will get an error about table auth_user not found.